# How to make two widgets sticky

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a flutter project, where in I want to make two widgets to be sticky on scroll.

EDIT:
I have a sticky app bar, a sticky tab bar, and within the tab body, I want a sticky widget.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean sticky bar will be placed under StickyTabs?

Comment: Yes @YeasinSheikh

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sliver_tools`](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools) [`multisliver`](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools#multisliver)

```dart
class WidgetThatReturnsASliver extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(slivers: [
      MultiSliver(
        pushPinnedChildren: false, // defaults to false
        children: <Widget>[
          SliverPinnedHeader(
            child: Text("pinnded header"),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 899,
            ),
          ),
          SliverPinnedHeader(
            child: Text("pinnded header2"),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 899,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: To make the tab bar sticky I have used SliverPersistentHeader, now within the tab body I want to make a widget sticky, if I use SliverPersistentHeader within the tab body, the sticky widget goes behind the tab bar, how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I thing  you can use [SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
body:Column(
Children:[Sticky Widget1,
          Sticky Widget2,       
         Expended(child:Listview(children: 
                [ScrollableWidget1,ScrollableWidget2,...]
                ))]
)
```

All the best!!!